# Code analysis C26408 — Replacing the m_pszHelpFilePath variable in InitInstance

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, free, code-analysis, chm

In my application's `InitInstance` function, I have the following code to rewrite the location of the CHM Help Documentation:

```
CString strHelp = GetProgramPath();
strHelp += _T("MeetSchedAssist.CHM");
free((void*)m_pszHelpFilePath);
m_pszHelpFilePath = _tcsdup(strHelp);
```

It is all functional but it gives me a code analysis warning:

> [C26408](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26408?view=msvc-160) Avoid `malloc()` and `free()`, prefer the `nothrow` version of `new` with `delete` (r.10).

---

When you look at the official documentation for [`m_pszHelpFilePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=msvc-160#m_pszhelpfilepath) it does state:

> If you assign a value to `m_pszHelpFilePath`, it must be dynamically allocated on the heap. The `CWinApp` destructor calls `free( )` with this pointer. You many want to use the `_tcsdup( )` run-time library function to do the allocating. Also, free the memory associated with the current pointer before assigning a new value.

Is it possible to rewrite this code to avoid the code analysis warning, or must I add a `__pragma`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can take advantage of the fact that `new` / `delete` map to usual `malloc`/`free` by default in Visual C++, and just go ahead and replace. The portability won't suffer much as MFC is not portable anyway. Sure you can use `unique_ptr<TCHAR[]>` instead of direct `new` / `delete`, like this:

```cpp
CString strHelp = GetProgramPath();
strHelp += _T("MeetSchedAssist.CHM");
std::unique_ptr<TCHAR[]> str_old(m_pszHelpFilePath);
auto str_new = std::make_unique<TCHAR[]>(strHelp.GetLength() + 1);
_tcscpy_s(str_new.get(), strHelp.GetLength() + 1, strHelp.GetString());
m_pszHelpFilePath = str_new.release();
str_old.reset();
```

##### For robustness for replaced `new` operator, and for least surprise principle, you should keep `free` / `strdup`.

If you replace multiple of those `CWinApp` strings, suggest writing a function for them, so that there's a single place with `free` / `strdup` with suppressed warnings.

Comment: I only have this one instance where I do this. But, if I change it to`delete` won't that then trigger yet another analysis warning about avoiding using `new` or `delete`? Or, are you saying it will be Ok to call `operator delete (m_pszHelpFilePath, std::nothrow);`. ?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, I've added an example how you could use `unique_ptr` instead of `new`/`delete` (didn't try it, wrote right here). But this is only to explain _technically_ part, I think you should not follow the advice in the warning.

Comment: Alright, I will simply suppress with a `__pragma`.

Answer (score 3):

You could (*should?*) use a smart pointer to wrap your reallocated `m_pszHelpFilePath` buffer. However, although this is not trivial, it can be accomplished without too much trouble.

First, declare an appropriate `std::unique_ptr` member in your derived application class:

```cpp
class MyApp : public CWinApp // Presumably
{
// Add this member...
public:
    std::unique_ptr<TCHAR[]> spHelpPath;
// ...
};
```

Then, you will need to modify the code that constructs and assigns the help path as follows (I've changed your C-style cast to an arguably better C++ cast):

```cpp
// First three (almost) lines as before ...
CString strHelp = GetProgramPath();
strHelp += _T("MeetSchedAssist.CHM");
free(const_cast<TCHAR *>(m_pszHelpFilePath));

// Next, allocate the shared pointer data and copy the string...
size_t strSize = static_cast<size_t>(strHelp.GetLength() + 1); 
spHelpPath std::make_unique<TCHAR[]>(strSize);
_tcscpy_s(spHelpPath.get(), strHelp.GetString()); // Use the "_s" 'safe' version!

// Now, we can use the embedded raw pointer for m_pszHelpFilePath ...
m_pszHelpFilePath = spHelpPath.get();
```

So far, so good. The data allocated in the smart pointer will be automatically freed when your application object is destroyed, and the code analysis warnings should disappear. However, there is one last modification we need to make, to prevent the MFC framework from attempting to free our assigned `m_pszHelpFilePath` pointer. This can be done by setting that to `nullptr` in the `MyApp` class override of `ExitInstance`:

```cpp
int MyApp::ExitInstance()
{
    // <your other exit-time code>
    m_pszHelpFilePath = nullptr;
    return CWinApp::ExitInstance(); // Call base class
}
```

However, this may seem like *much ado about nothing* and, as others have said, you may be justified in simply supressing the warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel that I will just leave it suppressed. But this is all useful info ... Interesting that you used `const_cast` ... :) Why I said that might become clear later!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That's the "least severe" C++ cast that will do the trick. Presumably, your code analyser warns you about using a C-style cast?

Comment: Yes, but I try to limit the question to one issue. In fact, in many instances I have been able to remove casts where I am passing as a `void*`. The coimpiler says it is implicit and not required. So that simplified things, but might not apply with this - not tested yet.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle No. Without a cast, you'll get an error: *error C2664: 'void free(void *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'void *'*

Comment: Hi. Note that using `const_cast` with `free` also triggers: *Don't use `const_cast` to cast away const or volatile (type.3).*.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Well, that's a daft rule in the code analyser. That's *exactly* what `const_cast` is designed to be used for!

Comment: I have the same warning for a LOGFONT. The CGridCtrl returns a const LOGFONT yet the CFont CreateFontIndirect wants a non-const LOGFONT. So it warns me.

Comment: Only thing is I already have a __pragma (26408) for using free. and not sure how to add a second (26492) for using const cast.

Comment: You can suppress multiple warnings in a single pragma: comma-separated list.

Comment: This does not work: `__pragma(warning(suppress:26408, 26492))`.

Comment: Sorry - **space** separated list. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-160)